# Java event.getKeyCode error

Tags: java, swing, object, keylistener, keyevent

So I am making this game. It is a ball bouncing around so far. But I want to add a purpoise of the game. So I added this Pad that I want the user to be able to move around. I searched around and couldn't find a good example how to use keyevents. Anyway, this is my code for the pad.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.EventQueue;


public class MainFrame extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    int diaPad = 120;
    long delay = 20;
    private int xx = 120;
    private int yy = 670;
    private int dxx = 6;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(xx,yy,120,15);

} 
public void run() {
    while(isVisible()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }
        repaint();
    }
}    
public void movePadRight() {
        if(xx + dxx < 0 || xx + diaPad + dxx > getWidth()) {
             dxx *= -1;
        }
        xx += dxx;

}
public void movePadLeft(){

        if(xx + dxx < 0 || xx + diaPad + dxx > getWidth()) {
             dxx *= -1;
        }
        xx -= dxx;

}

public void keyBoard(KeyEvent e){
   if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        movePadLeft();
   }
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        movePadRight();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see any errors in the code but when I compile the program, I get this

MainFrame.java:79: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable event
location: class MainFrame
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        movePadLeft();
   }
```

You are recieving  event as `e`.

That variable came from method argument

```
public void keyBoard(KeyEvent e){ <------
```

change it to `event`, that is more readable than simple `e`

```
public void keyBoard(KeyEvent event){
   if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        movePadLeft();
   }
```

Comment: I didnt get any errors, but the pad did not move. Do you perhaps know why that is?

Comment: Then what does this mean , in your question ?? `cannot find symbol symbol : variable event location:`

Comment: I am sorry, not from an english speaking country, what?

Comment: In the end of your post, you added an error, It's a compile time error because of the variable name mismatch. So I just confused when you said that there are no errors :) Just put a break point in you method and check weather the method is calling or not.

Comment: Oh yeah, about that, I am not using a developer tool.

Comment: Atleast `System.out.println("method called");`  :)  which shows a indication that it is calling.

Comment: It's not calling... and I couldn't add the keyBoard(); in the while(isVisible) class

Answer (score 2):

The `KeyEvent` variable is defined as `e`

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
```

Note: Use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead for handing key interaction in Swing. Key Listeners require component focus in order to work. They were designed for the old AWT graphical library and not really suited to Swing.

Answer (score 1):

Your KeyEvent variable is "e" not "event".  You have the wrong variable name.